# Classdiagram Angular2, association or dependency when injection and using routing

Tags: angular, uml, class-diagram

I need to create a class diagram of my newly created Angular2 application. I know the basic of creating class diagrams for a .NET application written in C#, but have never made one based on a Angular2 architecture.

**Scenario 1: Class that depend on service**

code:

```
@Injectable()
export class AmendmentAccountComponent implements OnInit 
{

    constructor(private accountService: AccountService) 
    {

    }
}
```

Lets say I have created a Component called AccountComponent. This component needs a service called AccountService that will be injected in the constructor. Right now I'm thinking of drawing a dependency (not association) from AccountComponent to AccountService that indicates it needs this dependency before the component will be executed.

A dependency compared to how it looks in this [article](https://nirajrules.wordpress.com/2011/07/15/association-vs-dependency-vs-aggregation-vs-composition/)

Is a dependency the correct way of showing (what i explained) in a class diagram?

**Scenario 2: Component uses routing (RouteConfig)**

Lets say I have a component named PageComponent. It has a class named the same. The component got some routing like resented in the RouteConfig code under here:

```
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/', name: 'Bookings', component: BookingsComponent },
    { path: '/bookings', name: 'Bookings', component: BookingsComponent, useAsDefault: true },
])
```

So a child of this component is the BookingsComponent. How should I draw this relationship in a class diagram? just with a normal association?

Hope someone can help, specially with scenario 2, which I'm not sure how to draw it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scenario 1: Yes, a dependency from AccountComponent to AccountService is correct.

Scenario 2: A dependency from PageComponent to BookingComponent is appropriate in this case too. A normal association (with the arrowhead pointing to BookingComponent) would imply that an *instance* of PageComponent could have a link (in the UML sense of the word) to an *instance* of BookingComponent. In Angular2, I would use an association only if class PageComponent would have a field of type BookingComponent.

For more information about UML modeling for Angular software, see [Technical design in UML for AngularJS applications](http://www.admiraalit.nl/admiraal/Technical-Design-For-AngularJS-Apps.pdf)

Comment: So you saying, if PageComponent uses routing to get to its child component by defining the <router-outlet></router-outlet> then i should use a dependency, else I use a association?

Comment: Use an association if the objects (the instances of the classes) are linked, otherwise use a dependency.
The meaning of "linked" in Angular terms is open for debate, but I would say that if class PageComponent has a field (a member, an attribute, a property, you name it) referring to an instance of BookingComponent, then use an association pointing from PageComponent to BookingComponent, otherwise use a dependency.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help.. I ended up making it a association because I'm important the child components and using the <router-outlet>.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Dependency is the right link:

[image]

**2)** Your `RouteConfig` is an array of associative arrays. The associative array itself seems to transport some sort of structure. This structure could well be presented as a single class. So I'd come up with this picture:

[image]

Comment: I understand the first image you made, but I'm not so sure about the second. 

Where are the PageComponent? I mean, PageComponent is the parent of BookingComponent, so there should be some sort of connection? or am i missing something?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Angular2. The 2nd picture is a representation of @RouteConfig.Maybe this is just some scaffold but then I can't guess its meaning related to your PageComponent.